# What kind query string format is this [key:value] , and how can I (re)create it?

Tags: php, laravel, query-string, urlencode, guzzle

I work with laravel - guzzle. I am using an api where I need to pass the query string like:

```
http:://domain.com/WS.php?secret=123123&app=app1&message=[key:value][key2:value][key3:value]
```

I am using this array to gather the get data:

```
$query = [
   'query' => [
       'app'     => 'app1',
       'secret'  => '123123',
       'message'   => [
            'key1'  => 'value',
            'key2'  => 'value',
            'key3'  => 'value',
        ]
    ]
]
```

I am not sure how I can convert this to the requested query string. Actually I am not familiar with this part `[key:value]` at all. I could manually create a string by my self(last resort perhaps) but I am looking for a better way than that to this.

Comment: can you post the api docs link?

Comment: @SaadSuri actually it is a proprietary api and kind a private one. And they have no documentation for the time being. The query above is  the only source I have. Besides I tried other formats as well but that is the only format that works.

Comment: Well it may vary then. the key value can be anything and it's hard to guess. you should contact to support or use some basic hint for what you're trying to query

Comment: the key value is just a representation I wrote here. They are specific key and variables.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question. I thought you asked what will be filled in key, value pairs. Absolutely sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported query string syntax for PHP arrays is:

```
variable[key?]=value
```

So,

```
message[key]=value&message[key2]=value
```

Supported doesn't mean the only way, it's just the expected way when dealing with PHP since it doesn't require you to do any additional manipulation.

There's really no limit to how you deal with input in your own application and if they designed it to read the stdin or input this way, that's what you have to send.  I doubt there's anything built in to support this, but why can't you just loop through the array to build a string for message:

```
foreach($message as $key=>$value) {
    $str .= "[$key:$value]";
}
```

Comment: You are right @Devon. when I use the url directly on a browser It works so I guess it is not a representation. I was suspicious if this was a standard format I couldn't  recognize or know about.  But it slowly turns out that it is not a standard format and I have to go with a custom function with a loop the way you mentioned.